# NgModel error in console

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I am trying to log the ngModel from this component so I can inspect it for educational purpose

```
<input ngModel name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" #firstname="ngModel" (change)="log(firstname)" class="form-control">
```

But I get this error, I don't seem to be able to diagnose the error.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" ("">First Name</label>
<input [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" 
[ERROR ->]#firstname="ngModel" (change)="log(firstname)" class="form-control 
</div><div class="form-grou"): ng:///AppModule/ContactFormComponent.html@3:79 Can't bind to 'ngModel' 
since it isn't a known property of
```

Comment: You need to remove the `#` before `#firstname="ngModel"`.  `#` is an alias for exporting a variable into your template, I believe.

Comment: Have you added FormsModule to the imports of your NgModule?

Comment: @JBNizet, yes I have

Comment: @JasonSpradlin, I tried that already. it returned undefined

Comment: it should return undefined... you want to have `(change)="log($event)"` because you're not supposed to export ngModel

Comment: ok but I have seen someone do this with exact same line of code.

Comment: Works fine here: http://plnkr.co/edit/obNiCvvnxvR2Cput4jBU?p=preview. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, just like I did (but without being able to reproduce it).

Comment: Note that I *can* reproduce the error, ny *not* importing FormsModule: http://plnkr.co/edit/gjy0BdwTOsrhtXRiGISm?p=preview. But you said you did.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks a lot that was the course of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Copy the module codes you added
2. Delete the module and make sure the project compile using (ng serve) successfully.
3. Regenerate the module and put back your codes.
4. add FormsModule inside app.modile.ts

```ts
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ContactFormComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule
      ],
```